# Display pdf files with fancybox on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, iframe, fancybox-2

I created the source code based on [fancybox v2.1.5](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), which displays pdf files and image files like light box view.

It works on Chrome (version 39.0.2171.65 m), but does not work on Firefox (version 33.1.1) well. On Firefox, when a pdf link is clicked, the browser starts to download the file. Regarding image files, the code works well on both Firefox and Chrome.

Source code is below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[href$=\".jpg\"] , a[href$=\".gif\"] , a[href$=\".png\"], .fancybox').fancybox();
  $('a[href$=\".pdf\"]').fancybox({
      autoSize: true,
      type:'iframe',
      iframe: {
       preload: false
      }
  });
  });
</script>

<a href=http://sample/publication/test.pdf>link</a>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0krraj5/) working fine in FF. Maybe show us a 'working' example. BTW why are you including 2 instances of jquery?

Comment: Check https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file and make sure you have Adobe Acrobat PDF plugin installed in Firefox